# Google Map KML doesn't display details and custom markers on website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a map and got the KML file.

In Google My Maps, the custom icons and details show up, however on my webpage the icons are white and when clicked, not details pop up.

Here is the code.

Anyone have experience with this?

```js
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
    {
        zoom: 4,
        center: {lat: 37.09024, lng: -95.712891},
    });

    //Create a Marker for My Position
    var myloc = new google.maps.Marker({
        clickable: false,
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mobile/mobileimgs2.png',
            new google.maps.Size(22,22),
            new google.maps.Point(0,18),
            new google.maps.Point(11,11)),
        shadow: null,
        zIndex: 999,
        map:map // your google.maps.Map object
    });

    //Add Spots Layer
    var kmlFile = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/spots_map/Spots.kml?'+(new Date()).getTime();
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlFile,
    {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map,
        preserveViewport: true
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Is Geolocation Enabled????
    if (navigator.geolocation) {


        //Get Current Position
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
        };               

        infoWindow.close();

        //Zoom Map to My Location
        map.setCenter(pos);
        map.setZoom(11);

        //Set my location
        // var me = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
        myloc.setPosition(pos);


    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
    } else {

        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) 
{

    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                    'Please Enable Geolocation for your Browser' :
                    'Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');

}
```

KML File:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <name>Spots</name>
        <NetworkLink>
            <name>Spots</name>
            <Link>
                <href>http://www.google.com/maps/...</href>
            </Link>
        </NetworkLink>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: check in browser console for error

Comment: The `MarkerImage` class is no longer supported (and hasn't been since 2012). You should use the [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) specification instead

Answer (score 0):

Answering here as I don't have sufficient points to comment.

**OPTION 1: Setting `suppressInfoWindows` to `false`**

The reason why the details doesn't pop up when you click the marker is because you have set the `suppressInfoWindows` to `true`. Set it to `false`. Here's a working fiddle the displays the info window when you click on the KML marker - http://jsfiddle.net/nkp2fhxb/50/. All I changed here is the KML file and set the `suppressInfoWindows` to `true`.

I've used the KML from http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/ListStyle/item-icon-hotspot.kml. Does your KML have the `<style>` tag which has an `href` that points to the right custom icon? May be that's reason why the icons are all white. The sample KML has this icon - http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/go-lv.png, which you can see on the fiddle.

**OPTION 2: Custom info window**

If you want to modify what gets displayed on the info window, keep `suppressInfoWindows` to `true`, and add a `click` event handler that displays the properties you need. Here's a fiddle that displays the position in addition to the default name and description of the marker on the info window - http://jsfiddle.net/nkp2fhxb/54/

```
google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
     var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
     showInContentWindow(kmlEvent.latLng,
     kmlEvent.featureData.name,
     kmlEvent.featureData.description);
});

function showInContentWindow(position, name, description) {
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "<p><strong>" + name + "</strong></p>" +
          "<p>" + description + "</p>" +
          "<p>" + position.lat() + "</p>" +
          "<p>" + position.lng() + "</p>",
          position: position,
          pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-20),
       })
      infowindow.open(map);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works is you define the marker in the code. My markers are defined in My Maps and which is then grabbed by the KML file. The custom icons are set in My Maps, but only the location (with a white icon) shows when the KML is used on the website.

Comment: Hmm..from what I understand, you first create the markers in Google My Maps and export it as a KML, and then host it in Google cloud. Am I right? Can you please post the KML file and a screenshot of the white icon if possible?

Comment: Did you try setting `suppressInfoWindows` to `false`? Did that pop up the details when you click on the icon?

Comment: The fiddle uses a KML - http://jsfiddle.net/nkp2fhxb/50/. The markers are not defined in the code :).

Comment: When I exported my KML, I selected "Entire Map", "Keep up to date with network link...", and "Export to .KML file instead of .KMZ". I compared your KML to my KML and it is very different do to the "Keep up to date with network link..." option. I want this option because I will be updated this map quite frequently and don't want to export every time I make a change. The other thing I am running into is the suppressInfoWindows=false works, but only displays the title of the "pin", not the other google information (address more specifically).